# Unable to authenticate using AWS Account with MFA enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-go-v2

I'm trying to authenticate to an AWS account that has MFA enabled. But, I'm not able to do so because it's throwing error. Also, I'm not getting any examples or clear documentation for performing it.

I'm following the example mentioned in the official [docs](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/gov2/sts/AssumeRole/AssumeRolev2.go).

```
// Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
// SPDX - License - Identifier: Apache - 2.0
// snippet-start:[sts.go-v2.AssumeRole]
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sts"
)

// STSAssumeRoleAPI defines the interface for the AssumeRole function.
// We use this interface to test the function using a mocked service.
type STSAssumeRoleAPI interface {
    AssumeRole(ctx context.Context,
        params *sts.AssumeRoleInput,
        optFns ...func(*sts.Options)) (*sts.AssumeRoleOutput, error)
}

// TakeRole gets temporary security credentials to access resources.
// Inputs:
//
//  c is the context of the method call, which includes the AWS Region.
//  api is the interface that defines the method call.
//  input defines the input arguments to the service call.
//
// Output:
//
//  If successful, an AssumeRoleOutput object containing the result of the service call and nil.
//  Otherwise, nil and an error from the call to AssumeRole.
func TakeRole(c context.Context, api STSAssumeRoleAPI, input *sts.AssumeRoleInput) (*sts.AssumeRoleOutput, error) {
    return api.AssumeRole(c, input)
}

func main() {
    roleARN := "arn:aws:iam::<AccountId>:role/<RoleName>"
    sessionName := "<SessionName>"
    serialNumber := "arn:aws:iam::<AccountId>:mfa/<DeviceName>"

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        panic("configuration error, " + err.Error())
    }

    client := sts.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    input := &sts.AssumeRoleInput{
        RoleArn:         &roleARN,
        RoleSessionName: &sessionName,
        SerialNumber:    &serialNumber,
        DurationSeconds: &[]int32{3600}[0],
        TokenCode:       &[]string{"<MFA Code>"}[0],
    }

    result, err := TakeRole(context.TODO(), client, input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got an error assuming the role:")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(result.AssumedRoleUser)
}

// snippet-end:[sts.go-v2.AssumeRole]
```

But, I'm not able to authenticate and I'm getting the below error always despite passing the MFA code.

```
Got an error assuming the role:
operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: d93830fb-f92e-4cdb-806f-cfdf116a6cef, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I tried to authenticate to the AWS Account (which has MFA enabled - using Go lang SDK v2 ) but I'm unable to do so. It always throws me this error and the documentation isn't quite proper as well.

```
panic: failed to assume role, operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 167f2d24-e6b4-4227-8470-97b39c7e3abd, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.

goroutine 1 [running]:
```

However, I'm able to do the same with Python SDK (Boto3) for AWS.

Comment: I have configured Microsoft Authenticator as my MFA Device which works fine with my aws cli and boto3 client. However, just for testing purpose, I'm hardcoding it or getting it from the command line using `scanln` from the fmt module

Comment: `client := sts.NewFromConfig(cfg)` Normally, API calls are made with an Access Key and a Secret Key. However, if you are using **temporary credentials** generated by STS, then it also requires a Security Token. Take a look at the Access Key -- if it starts with `AKIA` then it is a normal Access Key and shouldn't need a Security Token. However, if it starts with `ASIA` then they are temporary credentials requiring the Security Token. What does your start with?

Comment: Actually, I have a primary account and there are multiple sub accounts underneath it. I will be switching role using the AWS Extend Switch roles extension. 

So, in that case, I have my access key and secret set for the primary account and not for the other accounts. These details are configured in my aws config which looks like something below. 
```
[main_profile]
aws_account_id = <Account ID> 

[sub_profile]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:role/<RoleName>
source_profile = main_profile```.I'm unable to login to this sub_profile from the AWS SDK v2 for GO which works in boto3, cli

Comment: My Access Key starts with `AKIA` but it is for the main profile